# What are these called: to purse your lips?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

**[purse your lips](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/purse_2)**: to form your lips into a small tight round shape, for example to show that you do not approve of something

Look at these 3 pictures:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Are they all "**purse your lips**"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is. (That's the guy with the baseball cap.)

The second one is a frown. The emotion expressed is more anger than disapproval.

The third one is a weird face pulled by a model, probably to be comical.

The way to think about disapproval vs anger. Disapproval is when you have looked in the back of the fridge and found something has spoiled. Anger is when you notice that somebody has stolen your lunch out of the office fridge for the third time this week.

Comment: Agreed on your descriptions of the first two. I’d say in the third one, the funny face the model’s doing is “fish lips”

Comment: The original (coin) purses were bags gathered at the neck. 'Pursed lips' were thought to look like the neck of such a bag. [See this image](https://www.reddit.com/r/reenactors/comments/bf2b4u/i_made_some_purses_to_pay_the_troops_medieval/)